# Testing watchdog code with pytest

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, watchdog

I have a library that is using watchdog to check for new files in a directory and generate a copy of each file with some modifications.

The code is working well but now I want to add some tests to be sure it keeps working like this in the future. So, the test would basically create a file, move it to a watched directory and check the result file. The thing is, how can I wait for the file to be created?

Something like this would be needed:

```
1. Create file with content A
2. Move file to watched directory
3. Read file and check content is equals to B
```

I suppose that watchdog code will be executed between 2 and 3 or after 3 has finished. How can I ensure that 3 is run after watchdog code is executed?

Comment: There are multiple ways you can check if the file is created . To begin with you can start with an empty watch directory , execute your test steps and wait for a time till a new file is created [check this for monitoring a directory](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html).  If the watchdog code is something you could control , you can wait for it to return a status and proceed or if it is an executable, run it is a subprocess command and proceed based on its status.

Comment: Sure. Monitor a directory is easy but that would require to sleep between each check. Wouldn't this prevent my library to work? Watchdog works in a different thread my the library is only processing the files in the same thread that pytest.

Comment: You can spawn your library also in another thread and assert on new files to be created in your test.